# How can I get the checkbox to the left of the header using HTML / CSS

Tags: html, css

Write now, I'm using this code:

`<input type="checkbox" value="Aero Mexico Vacations" onchange="myAeroMexicoVacations(this)"><h1>AERO MEXICO VACATIONS</h1><br>`

I have multiple lines of this code all with different variations. The checkbox though comes up above the header, in this case, the accompanying checkbox would come up above "aero mexico vacations", like this:

◻

Aero Mexico Vacations

How can I get it so the checkbox is directly to the left of the header, like this:

◻ Aero Mexico Vacations

Comment: I'm new to HTML and can't find a solution. I'm sorry if it's relatively simple, I tried to research it but couldn't find anything.

Comment: make input and h1 inline-block i think that will work

Comment: @Abdul-RafayShaikh, no need to make the input `inline-block` it's `inline`.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Headers are [block](https://www.w3schools.com/htmL/html_blocks.asp) elements, which basically means that by default, they take up their entire line on the document. To get the input next to the text of the header, it needs to be inside the header

```
<h1>
    <input name="foo" type="text">
    Mexico Vacation
</h1>
```

or make the header inline

```
<input name="foo" type="text">
<h1 style="display:inline-block">
    <Mexico Vacation
</h1>
```

Answer (score 0):

An `<h1>` element is a [block-level element](https://www.w3schools.com/html/html_blocks.asp), so it will make a new line. Either make it an inline element, or add a `style="display: inline-block;"` attribute.